# What is pf apply in c?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, structure, function-pointers

I have a function

```
void join(table first, void(*pfapply)(const char *inp1,const void *inp2,void *addn),const void *addn);
```

here first is a instance of structure table as below

```
struct table
{
    char inp1;
    int inp2;
}struct table *first;
```

Now how to add this extra variable "addn" in this "join function"

In my symbol table i have two values inp1 and inp2..how to add addn to my structure using the above function?

I need to bind addn to the two variables inp1 and inp2...

Comment: The title of your question doesn't correspond to what you're asking in your question body (and I don't really understand what you're asking in your question body - `addn` is right there in the function, what's the problem?).

Comment: It is not quite clear , what exactly you want !!!

Comment: void SymTable_map (SymTable_t oSymTable,
void (*pfApply) (const char *pcKey,
const void *pvValue,
void *pvExtra),
const void *pvExtra);
SymTable_map iterates through the entire SymTable and applies pfApply on each binding.
pfApply takes a third parameter that is passed in from the map function.

Comment: you can't add to structure anything using a function. Structure cannot be changed this way. But this function is not used for this (as I can see by its definition). Write more about what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The `addn` is probably just the API being friendly and providing support for an *additional* parameter to the `pfapply()` callback.

This is a sign of good design, since it allows the callback to access some of its data without having to make it global.

If you don't need any additional data, just ignore the argument inside your apply-function, and call `join()` with `NULL` as the third argument.

You don't need to change anything in the declaration of `table`, all is fine.